# Is it still possible to run out of local references in a JNI method?

Tags: java-native-interface

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#EnsureLocalCapacity says that the JVM is guaranteed to give you 16; that it might give you some extras, and that -verbose:jni will tell you if you are depending on the extras. I've got a native method that uses many more than 16 local refs, never explicitly deletes one, and gets no messages on the subject with -verbose:jni. Is the default number in fact a whole lot bigger than 16 on a typical openjdk 1.7 or 1.8 on Linux or Windows 64 bit?

Comment: That probably depends on the specific JVM you're using. The Dalvik VM in Android currently [sets a maximum of 512](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/vm/Thread.h) local references (see `kJniLocalRefMax`)

Comment: I had some code that ran out, years ago, to the point where I had to start using the local-frame functions. I completely forget what it was actually doing. Could have been something in JPcap.